# optimization of nasty expression with nice symmetry between expressions

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the function  $\ f(x,y,z,\rho_a,\rho_b)=$

$ \log \left(1+ (x+ \rho_ay)^2 + \frac{(z+ \rho_by)^2}{1+(x+ 
\rho_by)^2} \right)+ \log\left(1+ (x+ \rho_by)^2 + \frac{(z+ \rho_ay)^2}{1+(x+ \rho_ay)^2} \right)$

For the given function above, I want to optimize over $\rho_a$ and $\rho_b$ and after I find the optimal answers, I would like to evaluate the function above.

It might not be easy to evaluate the above, however can anyone think of anything smart to take advantage of the symmetry between the two expressions within $f$?

I am guessing that $\rho_a= \rho_b$?

Thanks

Comment: Are there any constraints on $\rho_a,\rho_b$?

Comment: yes thanks for asking, $|\rho_a|^2 + |\rho_b|^2 \leq \frac{y^2}{1+2y^2}$ @AC_MOSEK

Comment: Is there any reason to believe this is convex? If not, what's its tie to convex optimization (or for that matter, "lagrange-multiplier" and "kkt", which I've already deleted.)

Comment: No there is no reason, you are right @MichaelGrant

Comment: @MichaelGrant do you have any idea how i can proceed with such an optimization?

Comment: Heh, I wouldn't worry about structure at all, and just throw a numerical method at it. It's just two variables. And what do you mean by "optimize over"? That is, are you minimizing or maximizing? Are x, y, and z fixed?

Comment: Thanks, I am actually maximizing over $\rho_{a}$ and $\rho_{b}$ and yes $x$, $y$ and $z$ are fixed.